# How to use GUI form created in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, intellij-idea

I'm creating a simple GUI form with one button in IntelliJ IDEA 9. The class which was created with the form is not JFrame or any other swing class. How I can call my form in my source code?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Simply go into the class associated with your form, press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> and choose "Form main()".

---

**Resources :**

- [GUI Designer Basics](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gui-designer-basics.html)

Comment: Thanks... but absolutely un intuitive... bad move from Jetbrains

Comment: The least RAD-style tool for Java.   Very hard to figure out.

Comment: Why does it create a main method. That's not how to do forms. One would either put it all in the constructor or call an init() type method from the constructor. What a silly choice from JetBrains.

Comment: The form bound to the class does not have a valid binding to the root component

Comment: I noticed accidentally while trying to understand this that Jetbrains does not even mention this GUI editor or Swing as a feature for CE or UE:  https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/  I wonder if support is going to be dropped for v14?

Comment: I imagine it's because only three people in the world still make UIs with Swing in Java, and the other 3/4 of a Billion Java users are all making EnterpriseSpringLoadedHammerFactories that run in some J2EE container.  Java on the desktop? what's that?

Comment: Just wanted to note that the link is dead.

Answer (score 104):

I was stumped when IntelliJ consistently errored out when choosing `Form main()` from the insert menu, with an error message saying something about an invalid root component.

It turns out it means that the `JPanel` that is the main (root) component of your `Form` needs to have a field bound to it, and by default it doesn't do this.

Simply select the `JPanel` in the form designer, and give it a name (`field name`) in the property pane.

After this it will generate the `main()` just fine.

Comment: How intuitive! After finally generating that main method, I get `java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: contentPane cannot be set to null`

Answer (score 1):

First add `private JPanel Main;` inside the class. Then, in the form's panel properties, add `Main` to the field name. Then, go to your class and from the `Alt` + `Insert` menu, select `Main`.

Now, the error wont come.

Comment: yes that was the critical piece.