# How do I create a new Swing app in IntelliJ IDEA Community edition?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have created a new project using the Create New Project Wizard, by choosing "create project from scratch" but it's completely empty (no java classes at all, so I manually created a new swing form inside the empty project).

In many other IDEs I have used there is a way to click once, and get a new "new Gui project", and I usually expect it in the "File -> New Project" wizard or something, comparable.

There is a new project wizard in the IntelliJ IDEA IDE, but it only seems it can create a blank project, and then I can manually add a form to it. So I did that.  But then, that lacks any of the usual Java code that you would expect it to have, to open up that form and show it as an application.

I am trying to understand the features and capabilities of IntelliJ IDEA, and it seems strong as a very fast and efficient editor and debugger and build system GUI wrapper around the ANT build system, but I was wondering if there are more "RAD" features that I have merely overlooked.   I have done a bit of googling and reading the docs, but I haven't found much about using IntelliJ IDEA to build a GUI application in Java.

Where I'm currently stuck is when I tried to build and run my empty project with an empty form in it, and I get to some kind of "Run" target configuration screen, and I tried clicking the [+] icon, and adding "MyForm01" which is the empty swing form I created, and it says in a dialog box "MyForm01 is not acceptable".   I know enough java to know that the basic "GUI app skeleton code" is not being auto-generated by the IDE.  I could go and copy and paste something from the internet, but my interest here is in knowing whether the tool can automatically be used to build a GUI, with a workflow as simple as other RAD-style GUI builder tools, including NetBeans, which is the java tool I am most comfortable using, or Delphi, which is my main everyday tool, which is Pascal based, rather than Java.

Comment: It's hard to tell if this is a genuine request for information, or merely a complaint about the tools.

Comment: It *could* be a request for information, but the second paragraph could use some un-biasing, and the last two paragraphs could disappear altogether...then it'd be a request for information.

Comment: I apologize for the testy way it was originally phrased. I've edited it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no such thing as GUI project in IDEA. You can add GUI forms there at any time you need, just by RightClick -> New -> GUI Form. You can create GUI app from it just by adding `main()` method into the form binding class. IDEA does the job for you if you hit Alt-Ins (or menu Code->Generate) when in the binding class editor. The only requirement for this is to place correct name for the form's root panel.

You also should may want this manual to discover some other things: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/designing-gui-major-steps.html. Anyway, the GUI builder is pretty intuitive.

Comment: Thank you.  That confused me as most other big and popular Java IDEs do have this.

Comment: Please note that the `UI Designer` plugin needs to be enabled in order to create a new `GUI Form`...

Comment: I have UI Designer plugin enabled but I dont have GUI Form in inspector New menu. What is wrong?

Comment: Kirill, be sure that you are using the context menu inside the project  structure pane. It's similar to class creation, not module or project. Check this out: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-opening-forms.html

Comment: **Clarification**, expand your project and then right-click the directory the source lives in (eg `src`). Even [the screenshot in the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-template-based-files.html) makes this unclear.

Comment: I got "The form bound to the class does not have a valid binding for the root component" when I tried to Alt-Ins Generate the main() method on a simple Hello World GUI app. I had to click inside the form designer, but not on any control, to select the root JPanel control, then I had to enter a value in the "field name" property. Then the Alt-Ins generation of main() method worked. Why don't they give the root JPanel a default field name? Seems crazy to me.

Answer (score 19):

The following instruction applies to IntelliJ Idea 14.

1. Enable UI Designer

   1. File → Settings → Plugins → UI Designer
2. Enable generate Java class

   1. File → Settings → Editor → GUI Designer → change Generate GUI into “Java source code”
3. Go to the project view, and right click the package name where you want the generated Java class to be stored

   1. On the context menu, choose New → GUI Form, and set the bound class
   2. In the designer, it will automatically put a Jpanel on the window. Choose Jpanel, and first set the Layout manager to GridLayoutManager(IntelliJ).
   3. Adding components as needed, make sure to give some value to “field name”. This value will become the name of this component in the form class.
   4. You can preview the form by right click and then choose preview.
   5. When you are done, change the layout manager for Jpanel to “GridBagLayout”.
4. Click on Build → Make Project to generate Java source codes and store them in the bound Java class.

Answer (score 11):

IntelliJ IDEA is first of all a very smart editor, not a RAD tool like Delphi.

However, it has a powerful gui editor - just right click on any package in the Project view on the left, and select `New GUI form` or `New Dialog`, and it will let you create GUI. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899525/how-to-use-gui-form-created-in-itellij-idea) question provides more info about running the gui.

Comment: The linked question and the Alt-Ins is the way to go.  Accepted the other answer because it's more helpful to others who come along and mentions the Alt->Ins (or Code->Generate) directly in the body of his answer. I really appreciate both answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Creating a New GUI Form or Dialog

**To create a new GUI form**

1.On the main menu, choose File | New, as described in the section Creating Files.

2.On the pop-up menu, choose GUI Form.

3.Specify the name of the new form, and select the layout manager.

4.Check the option Create bound class, and specify the bound class name.

5.Click OK.

**To create a new dialog**

1.On the main menu, choose File | New, as described in the section Creating Files.

2.On the pop-up menu, choose Dialog.

3.Specify the name of the new dialog.

4.Specify the following options:

Generate main() method that creates and shows dialog.

Generate OK handler.

Generate Cancel handler.

5.Click OK.

**To create a File Template from a GUI form**

1.Create a GUI form or open it in the GUI Designer.

2.On the Main menu, choose Tools | Save File as Template. The File Templates dialog displays the source code of the form. The extension of the new template is .form
3.Specify the template name, and click OK.

**To create a new GUI form from a File Template**

1.In the Project tool window, right-click the package where you want to create the new form.
2.On the context menu choose New. The submenu contains items for all defined File Templates, including GUI forms.
3.Select the desired GUI form template on the context menu, and give it a name when prompted.

**Creating Snapshots**

The Snapshot feature enables you to convert GUI forms created by some other means into IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer Forms. All you need to do is run your application and save a part of the running application's component tree as a GUI Designer form. From then on, you can use the GUI Designer to extend or modify the form.

You can work with the layout and code in the GUI Designer just as you do with Forms originally created with the GUI Designer.

**To take a Snapshot of an existing dialog**

1.Open the module that contains source code for the dialog you want to capture.

2.Select the Application Run Configuration, make sure that the option Enable capturing form snapshots is checked, and run the application.

3.In the running application, perform whatever interaction is necessary to open the dialog you want to capture.

4.In the Project tool window, right-click the target package and choose New | Form Snapshot on the context menu. If the application is not yet running, IntelliJ IDEA prompts you to run it, and then prepare the application for taking snapshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HsFh.png)

The Create Form Snapshot dialog box appears.

5.In the IntelliJ IDEA's Create Form Snapshot dialog, select the top-level component to be included in the snapshot, enter the form name, and click Create Snapshot button. The new form created this way is not bound to any class. You have to bind it to a class yourself.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCEfP.png)

**Opening Existing GUI Forms**

1.Open form files the same way you open source code or text files for editing. Locate the file in the appropriate navigation view, select it, and do one of the following:

-Double-click.

-Choose Jump to Source on the context menu.

-Press F4.

Each form opens in a separate tab in the same space occupied by the Editor for source code files. You can have source code/text files and form files open simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my basic shell for a one-window GUI application:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * <p>Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * <p>Date: 1/25/23
 * <p>Time: 7:59 PM
 *
 * @author Miguel Mu\u00f1oz
 */
public class GenericUIApp extends JPanel {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Generic UI App");
    frame.add(new GenericUIApp());
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack(); // Sets the window to fit the natural size of its content pane
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  
  private GenericUIApp() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    // replace this code with your UI code.
    add(new JLabel("Put your UI Contents here."));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(100, 100, 100, 100, getBackground()));
  }
}
```

Comment: The question was how to use the IntelliJ IDEA IDE to generate a Swing APP.
This answer is how to code one by hand.

The above does combine both into a single unit of compilation, and is useful for testing out ideas, but it's probably not the way you would want to code a real production app.

Comment: @WarrenP That's exactly how I do it in a real production app. I do a lot more, of course, but that's my starting point. I do multi-window apps the same way. "Code one by hand" is certainly a correct answer, and that's what I'm doing here. (A lot of people extend JFrame, but I find that approach to be more trouble than it's worth.)
I could have included a line to set the platform look and feel, but that's optional.

Comment: Sure, code by hand is a way to do it, I'm just saying, that's not what the original question was here.    This is perhaps a valid workaround if the IDE doesn't have a way to generate a new form, or a main application from a template.    Most IDEs (say, Netbeans,  or Delphi, or Visual Studio) have code generators, which is what the question is about.